# Access office 365 group using ews api

Tags: microsoft-teams, ewsjavaapi

I am trying to access office 365 groups using ews java api using impersonation. I am getting error:

```
 The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it.
```

Code:

```
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("admin@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com", "passwordxxx");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.setImpersonatedUserId(
            new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "group-smtp@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"));
FolderView folderView = new FolderView(50);
FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.findFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, folderView);
```

The aim is to get channel messages of the team associated with this group. According to this: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/retention-policies-teams?view=o365-worldwide)

The channel messages are stored in group's mailbox's Conversation History/Team Chat folder

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the messages in a Teams channel. You could use [List Channel messages graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Comment: Yes, I am very well aware of this API. But it has limitations it requires a signed user since it's a protected API. I believe there has to be some way to use **EWS or Powershell**. I am unable to find one.